# MSQL select regardless of distinct or not distinct (count greater than zero)

Tags: mysql, insert, distinct

I've found many ways to show only distinct results, but how would I select both the distinct and the non distinct together? Consider these tables:

```
    A
    ---------------------------------
    |    id    |   col1   |   col2  |
    ---------------------------------
    |    1     |    aa    |   dd    |
    ---------------------------------
    |    1     |    bb    |    ee   |
    ---------------------------------
    |    2     |    cc    |    ff   |
    ---------------------------------

    B
    ---------------------------------
    |    id    |   col1   |   col2  |
    ---------------------------------
    |    1     |    a     |    d    |
    ---------------------------------
    |    2     |    b     |    e    |
    ---------------------------------
    |    3     |    c     |    f    |
    ---------------------------------

    C
    ---------------------------------
    |    id    |   col1   |   col2  |
    ---------------------------------
    |    1     |    x     |    1a   |
    ---------------------------------
    |    2     |    y     |    2b   |
    ---------------------------------
    |    3     |    x     |    3c   |
    ---------------------------------
```

A user supplies to me an id and a list of columns, say id = 1 and columns = (a.col1, b.col1, and c.col2). How would I construct a query to give me all column information where the id matches, regardless of how many times the id appears?

My current query is:

```
    SELECT a.col1, b.col1, c.col2
    FROM a
        LEFT JOIN b
            ON b.id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN c
            ON  c.id = b.id
    WHERE a.id = 1
```

The problem is that this only gives me one result from table A when I'd like to get both results (or all results from any table that happens to have repeating ids that match). Note: In table A, the columns id and col1 together make up the primary key which is why I have repeating ids.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want matches in ABC, AB, AC and BC?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Do you mean that you want to select multiple rows from table A if there is more than one row with id=1? That should already work with your current query.

Comment: My example table had a mistake which has been fixed. So sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In the data in the question, there is no repeating id in table A.  The query should be returning only one row from A, then.

However, your query has an error.  The second join should be back to the first table, not the second:

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col1, c.col2
FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b
        ON b.id = a.id
    LEFT JOIN c
        ON  c.id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 1
```

You had `c.id = b.id` and `b.id` could be NULL if there is no match in that table.

Also, from your description, I wonder if a `union` would be the best approach:

```
select a.col1, 'a'
from a
where id = 1
union all
select b.col1, 'b'
from b
where id = 1
union all
select c.col2, 'c'
from c
where id = 1
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I spent a long time carefully typing up my question then a last minute change with copy paste messed it up, oops.